# How to add unique ID for react native app without use accessibilityLabel

Tags: react-native, automation, appium, cross-platform

I need to write automation test for app that written in React Native.
Our developers have some problem with unique ID for each elements in app.
Right now, React Native does not support for unique ID, but support contentDescription via accessibilityLabel.
The problem is that we can't currently use accessibilityLabel attribute, because we need it for accessibility in the future.

The question is, how to give unique ID for elements and not find them by xpath, since xpath doesn't suit us.